# Installing Android Sdk (not with Eclipse)

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio and Android sdk for Linux. Surprisingly, I didn't find any tutorial of how to install Android sdk, even at the official android web site. As for Android Studio, there is one there, it says that I just have to unzip Android Studio to the appropriate directory.

So what about Android Sdk installing?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but you should be able to load the SDK from within Android Studio via the toolbar SDK manager (an android with a blue square and a down arrow)

Comment: read the documentation http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about Linux, but the Windows version of the SDK requires no "installing" - you just extract the contents of the archive and run the executable file. This then displays the SDK manager, which allows you to download the various Android development components. And since Windows is a lot more "needy" than Linux when it comes to installations vs just running stuff, I'm guessing that the Linux version will work the same ;)

The only other thing that you need to do is to add a `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable, and set it to the path where you extracted the SDK archive contents.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to post, however might be of use to anyone referring this later : http://www.moreontech.com/getting-started-android-studio-linux/